# Complex Matrix Equation

Tags: matrices

I've be been struggling to deal with the following problem. Consider the expression (1), 
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
\underset{m\times N}{\mathbf{z}}=\underset{m\times N}{\mathbf{A}}\underset{N\times 1}{\mathbf{x}}
\end{equation}

for which all the quantities are defined on the complex field $\mathbb{C}$, $m<N$ and $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A})=m$ (full row-rank). In this case, given that 
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\underset{m\times N}{\mathbf{u}}=\underset{m\times N}{\mathbf{A}}\underset{N\times N}{\mathbf{J}}\underset{N\times 1}{\mathbf{x}}
\end{equation}

with $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{J})=N$ (full-rank), how can I put $\mathbf{u}$ as a function of the vector $\mathbf{z}$ (and possibly other matrices related to the problem)? I have tried Hadamard, Kronecker, Khatri-Rao products and $\operatorname{vec}()$ operator, but with no success.

Moreover, I point out that any pseudo-inverse (least-squares) solution is not acceptable in this case, unless you prove it is the only possible solution we have. Could anyone give some clue on that? If the problem statement is not clear enough, pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A^+$ denote the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$ and consider the matrix
$$P = (I - A^+A)$$
This matrix is an projector into the nullspace of $A,\,$ i.e.
$$AP = (A - AA^+A) = (A-A) = 0$$
An arbitrary vector $y$ can be used to *perturb* the $x$ vector without affecting the value of $z,\,$ i.e.
$$A(x + Py) = Ax = z$$
Therefore $x$ cannot be a function of $z.\,$ So, although both $z$ and $u$ are functions of $x,\,$ $\,u\,$ **cannot** be written as a function of $z.$

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a little ill-posed, and this might be why you’re struggling with it.  Is  $\textbf{z}$ a function of $\textbf{A}$, a function of $\textbf{x}$ or both?  Each one will yield a slightly different answer.

If $\textbf{z}$ is a function of $\textbf{x}$ then you want

$$
\textbf{AJx}= \textbf{z(Jx)}.
$$

If it’s a function of $\textbf{A}$ then

$$
\textbf{AJx}= \textbf{z(AJ)}
$$

Lastly, if it’s a function of both $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{x}$ we can write it one of two ways:

$$
\textbf{AJx}= \textbf{z(AJ,x)}= \textbf{z(A,Jx)}.
$$

Comment: In fact, the way I see it makes me thing about the following: suppose there is a mathematical way, in some sense, to find x from z=Ax, if we hypothesize z and A are known. However, if we put a known matrix J between A and x, which matrices should I use, by performing the same math procedure described above so that I can find the same x? I see that you should use "AJ" and a "u". How can we obtain this known u from z and A?